# Субфакториал двоичного числа

Tags: c++, c, логические-выражения

Подскажите пожалуйста, что делают два восклицательных знака перед скобкой

```
!!(b.n[1] & m)
```

где `b.n[1]` и `m` двоичные числа

Answer (score 2):

Двойное отрицание. Дважды примененный оператор `!`: `!!x == !(!x)`.

По сути, просто превращение в логическое значение. `!!x` — первый `!x` дает `true` для нулевого значения и `false` для ненулевого, второй `!` обращает.

В принципе, во многих местах можно обойтись и без них (хотя не везде) — например, в `if (!!(b.n[1] & m))`.

Как маленькое замечание — говорить о двоичности чисел бессмысленно. `int m = 0x03` ничем не отличается от `int m = 3`, например :) Как вы отличаете двоичные числа от десятичных? Только *по записи* на экране/бумаге/etc.

Comment: У меня такая функция, на вход подается структура b, где b.n[1] значение unsigned int

    int s = 0;
    for (unsigned m = 0x800000; m != 0x8000; m >>= 1) { 
        s <<= 1;
        s |= !!(b.n[1] & m);
    }
    return s;

Comment: Здесь нельзя без нее (или надо использовать что-то типа тернарного оператора), так как в выражении `s |=` в правой части требуется именно 0 или 1. Выражение `!!` делает из 0 — 0, а из любого ненулевого значения 1.

Comment: Я понял в чем суть, спасибо большое

Comment: Спасибо здесь имеет вид щелчка мышкой на треугольнике вверх слева от ответа; большое спасибо — щелчок на "птичке" там же...